# How do you create a custom MapType with BranFlake GWT-Maps-V3 API?

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3

I'm attempting to use the (unofficial) Google Maps V3 JavaScript API via the Branflake (or Branflake2267) GWT/Java library.  All the base libraries have been loaded and I got the standard Google satellite imagery to appear no problem.

Now, however, I want to create a custom map type (`MapType`) that provides its own `Element` values for display.  The provided `ImageMapType` and `StyledMapType` are not sufficient.

The JavaScript library supports this and Google even provides an [example CoordMapType map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-base) in their documentation.

***What I'd like is to know how to do this very thing using the GWT library that Brandon Donnelson has created.***

My attempts so far...

I tried creating a pure Java class that `implements MapType` but that fails as an incorrect object type:

```
class FooMap implements MapType {...}

@com.google.gwt.maps.client.maptypes.MapTypeRegistry::set(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)([string:'FooID', Java object: com.example.FooMap@1360213231])
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (Error)@com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl::apply(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)([JavaScript object(44), JavaScript object(32), JavaScript object(46)]): Expected value implementing google.maps.MapType
```

I figured it had to be a JavaScript object so tried extending that but it also fails:

```
class FooMap extends JavaScriptObject implements MapType {...}

JavaScriptObject must be created from JavaScript.  [paraphrased]
```

I tried creating it via JavaScript but no luck:

```
static public FooMap newInstance(MapOptions options) {
     return createJso(options).cast();
}

static private final native JavaScriptObject createJso(MapOptions options) /*-{
    return new $wnd.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), options);
}-*/;

[ERROR] Line 296: Instance fields cannot be used in subclasses of JavaScriptObject
```

I removed my local members (dunno where to put them but at least I can test) but the `createJso()` method still throws an exception:

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) @com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl::apply(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)([JavaScript object(30), JavaScript object(32), JavaScript object(33)]): Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null
```

Which, as near as I can tell from other posts, is because I haven't yet created a map and thus a map-canvas element...  But that's what I'm trying to do.

I'm currently out of ideas so thought the good folks here might have some ideas.  I'll add updates (or maybe an answer <hopeful look>) if I make any progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's how I accomplished it.  Note that this is just a "tile provider" for an actual Google Map, not the map itself.

```
static public final class MyMap extends JavaScriptObject {
    // These are actually done through JSNI calls because JavaScriptObject
    // doesn't allow adding local member variables in derived classes.
    // "DisplayLayer" is my own details about how to display these map tiles.
    // @getter @setter private DisplayLayer displayLayer;
    // @getter @setter private String urlPrefix;

    protected MyMap() {}

    static public MyMap newInstance(MapOptions options, DisplayLayer layer) {
         MyMap map = createJso(options).cast();
         map.setDisplayLayer(layer);
         if (layer != null) {
             ...
         }
         return map;
    }

    static private native JavaScriptObject createJso(MapOptions options) /*-{
        var map = new Object();
        map.tileSize = new $wnd.google.maps.Size(256, 256);
        map.maxZoom = 31;
        map.getTile = function(point, zoom, owner) {
            return @com.example.project.MyMap::getTile(Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/maps/client/base/Point;ILcom/google/gwt/dom/client/Document;)(this, point, zoom, owner);
        };
        return map;
    }-*/;

    private native void setDisplayLayer(DisplayLayer layer) /*-{
        this.displayLayer = layer;
    }-*/;

    private native DisplayLayer getDisplayLayer() /*-{
        return this.displayLayer;
    }-*/;

    private native void setUrlPrefix(String prefix) /*-{
        this.urlPrefix = prefix;
    }-*/;

    private native String getUrlPrefix() /*-{
        return this.urlPrefix;
    }-*/;

    private native void setVisible(boolean visible) /*-{
        this.visible = visible;
    }-*/;

    private native boolean isVisible() /*-{
        return this.visible;
    }-*/;

    static public Element getTile(JavaScriptObject jsmap, Point point, int zoom, Document owner) {
        final MyMap map = jsmap.cast();
        final DisplayLayer dl = map.getDisplayLayer();
        final ImageElement img = owner.createImageElement();
        img.getStyle().setWidth(256, Style.Unit.PX);
        img.getStyle().setHeight(256, Style.Unit.PX);
        ... set img.src and various CSS styles based on display-layer ...
        return img;
    }
}
```